# Primitive Roots of Unity

Tags: code-golf, number-theory, complex-numbers

Let `z` be a complex number. `z` is an nth **primitive root of unity** if for a certain positive integer `n` [image] and for any positive integer `k < n` [image].

### Challenge

Write a full program or function that, given a positive integer `n` as input, outputs all of the nth primitive roots of unity. You may output them in polar form (`e^θi` or `e^iθ`, argument should be a decimal with at least 2 decimal places) or rectangular form (`a + bi` or a similar form, real and imaginary parts should also be decimals), and they may be outputted in your language's list/array format or as a string with the numbers separated by spaces or newlines. Built-ins that calculate the nth roots of unity or the nth primitive roots of unity are not allowed.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins.

### Sample Inputs and Outputs

```
6 -> e^1.05i, e^-1.05i # polar form
3 -> e^2.094395i, e^-2.094395i # any number of decimal places is OK as long as there are more than 2
8 -> 0.707 + 0.707i, 0.707 - 0.707i, -0.707 + 0.707i, -0.707 - 0.707i # rectangular form
1 -> 1 + 0i # this is OK
1 -> 1 # this is also OK
4 -> 0 + i, 0 - i # this is OK
4 -> i, -i # this is also OK
```

Comment: So +-i are not solution of z^8=1?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Jelly, <s>11</s> 9 bytes

*Thanks to @Dennis for -2 bytes!*

```
Rg=1O÷H-*
```

I wanted to generate the numbers coprime to N by folding set difference over all of the roots of unity from 1 to N, but I couldn't figure out how so I used @Dennis's method.

```
Rg=1O÷H-*         Monadic chain:          6
R                 Range                   [1,2,3,4,5,6]
 g                Hook gcds with range    [1,2,3,2,1,6]
  =1              [gcds equal to one]     [1,0,0,0,1,0]
    O             Replicate indices       [1,5]
     ÷H           Divide by half of N     [1/3,5/3]
       -          Numeric literal: - by itself is -1.
        *         Take -1 to those powers [cis π/3,cis 5π/3]
```

<s>Try it [here](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=Umc9MU_Dt0gtKg&input=&args=Ng)</s>. Valid in [this version](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/blob/cff64821686eb6536294e1e67bbc6debf228e25b/jelly.py) of Jelly, but may not be in versions after February 1, 2016.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/blob/master/docs/code-page.md)

```
Rg=1O°÷×ı360Æe
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=Umc9MU_CsMO3w5fEsTM2MMOGZQ&input=&args=OA)

#### How it works

**z = e<sup>2tπi</sup>** is an **n**<sup>th</sup> root of **1** if and only if **t = k / n** for some integer **k**.

**z** is *primitive* if and only if **k** and **n** are coprime.

```
Rg=1O°÷×ı360Æe  Main link. Input: n

R               Yield [1, ..., n].
 g              Compute the GCDs of reach integer and n.
  =1            Compare the GCDs with 1.
    O           Get all indices of 1's.
                This computes all the list of all k in [1, ..., n] 
                such that k and n are coprime.
     °          Convert the integers to radians.
      ÷         Divide the results by n.
       ×ı360    Multiply the quotient by the imaginary number 360i.
            Æe  Map exp over the results.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Julia, 48 bytes

```
n->cis(360deg2rad(filter(k->gcd(k,n)<2,1:n))/n)
```

This is a lambda function that accepts an integer and returns an array of complex floats. To call it, assign it to a variable. It uses the same approach as Dennis' Jelly answer.

Ungolfed:

```
function f(n::Int)
    # Get the set of all k < n : gcd(k,n) = 1
    K = filter(k -> gcd(k,n) < 2, 1:n)

    # Convert these to radian measures
    θ = deg2rad(K)

    # Multiply by 360, divide by n
    θ = 360 * θ / n

    # Compute e^iz for all elements z of θ
    return cis(θ)
end
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 27 bytes

```
:1-tGYf1X-!\Xpg)2j*YP*G/Ze!
```

Uses [release (9.3.1)](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL/releases/tag/9.3.1), which is earlier than this challenge.

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OjEtdEdZZjFYLSFcWHBnKTJqKllQKkcvWmUh&input=OA)

(The online compiler uses a newer release, but the code runs in release 9.3.1 and gives the same result)

#### Explanation

There are three main steps:

1. Generate integers `0`,`1`,...,`N-1`, corresponding to all roots.
2. Keep only integers corresponding to primitive roots. These are identified using the prime factor decomposition of `N`.
3. Generate the actual roots with an imaginary exponential.

Code:

```
:1-           % 1. Implicit input "N". Produce vector [0,1,...,N-1]
t             %    duplicate
GYf           % 2. Prime factors of N
1X-           %    remove factor "1" if present (only if N==1)
!\            %    all combinations of [0,1,...,N-1] modulo prime factors of N
Xpg           %    logical "and" along the prime-factor dimension
)             %    index into original vector [0,1,...,N-1] to keep only primitive roots
2j*YP*G/Ze    % 3. Imaginary exponential to produce those roots
!             %    transpose for better output format
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 46 bytes

This is a non-"golfing language" implementation of [Thomas Kwa](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/39328/thomas-kwa)'s Jelly answer.

```
->n{(1..n).map{|j|1i**(4.0*j/n)if j.gcd(n)<2}}
```

Ungolfed:

```
def r(n)
  (1..n).each do |j|
    if j.gcd(n) == 1    # if j is coprime with n, then this will be a primitive root of unity
      p 1i**(4.0*j/n)   # print the fourth power of i**(j/n), i.e. the root of unity
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## Matlab 49 bytes

```
n=input('');q=0:n-1;exp(i*2*pi/n.*q(gcd(n,q)==1))
```

Didn't get the task at the first time, but now here it is. Outputs as follows:

```
6
ans =
    0.5000 + 0.8660i   0.5000 - 0.8660i
```

Comment: Your answer displays all roots of unity, not just the *primitive* ones.

Comment: @flawr thanks for remark, I didn't get the task at first. I edited solution

Answer (score 1):

### ES6, 96 bytes

```
n=>[...Array(n).keys()].filter(i=>g(i,n)<2,g=(a,b)=>a?g(b%a,a):b).map(i=>'e^'+Math.PI*2*i/n+'i')
```

Polar form was the shortest output.

Answer (score 1):

## PARI/GP, 41 bytes

Pretty straightforward: find the numbers from 1 to n which are coprime to n, then

```
n->[exp(2*Pi*I*m/n)|m<-[1..n],gcd(n,m)<2]
```

There has to be some shorter way, but this was the best I could find.